# Customize the web portal

Tags: asp.net, html

I am developing a portal site with asp.net 3.5/4.0. The screen likes below:
[image: The current screen]

I used CreateUserWizard to implement it. The code structure likes:

```
  <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard2" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderColor="#FFDFAD"
    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em"
    OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" DisableCreatedUser="true" 
        LoginCreatedUser="false">
        <table>blah blah</table>
  </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
</asp:Content>
```

Now I want to add some statement on the right. The screen will be liking:
[image: New Screen]

I need your kind help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a table is the most easy way, the other way is to place 2 divs.

```
 <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <table border="0">
<tr><td>
  <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard2" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderColor="#FFDFAD"
    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em"
    OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" DisableCreatedUser="true" 
        LoginCreatedUser="false">
 </td><td>
   Text here
  </td>
   </tr>
  </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
</asp:Content>
```